# Network with conjure-up single machine openstack

Tags: networking, ssh, juju, openstack, conjure-up

I just installed an Openstack single machine using conjure-up on A ESXi VM . I have successfully lunched an instance on it but i still have 2 issues :

1- I cant access the instance Assigned floating IP from any where (SSH,PING....etc).

2- Cant get the Console to work right in the Horizon .

Any help would appreciated let me know what details you need.

Regards Thamer

Answer (score 0):

All the Assigned floating IPs are private and you can only access them from within the host server. So to answer your questions:

1. Because you installed OpenStack using conjure-up, you better use juju to orchestrate the services (keystone, nova,...). For example you want to configure keystone, do these:

   - Find the keystone machine number

   $ juju machines

   - Then ssh into the keystone container:

   $ juju ssh
2. To access the OpenStack Dashboard service/horizon from outside the host machine, you have to create a NAT rule on the host:

   $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d  --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination :443